# Webform added to MVC Application throws error on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a `MVC` application that I am integrating some already existing `webforms` into. The page loads correctly, and loads a dropdown that pulls from SQL, from there the webform has an additional search that will run a SQL query with a button action event, when that button is clicked it returns an error Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. The URL is spelled correctly and is the same URL that is loaded initially. Is there a setting I am missing somewhere? This is known working code in a existing webforms application that I am trying to integrate into a Mvc application.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("My query"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            layouts.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            layouts.DataTextField = "layouts";
            layouts.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }

        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("My query"))
        {
            cmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            users.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            users.DataTextField = "email";
            users.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }
    }
}

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var email1 = users.Text;
    string strValue = "";
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("My query"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", users.Text);
                SqlDataReader myreader;
                con.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    if (myreader.IsDBNull(0))
                    {
                        updated.Visible = true;
                        break;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strValue = myreader["Clients"].ToString();
                        strValue = myreader.GetString(0);
                        string[] client1 = strValue.Split('|');
                        foreach (string clientarray in client1)
                        {
                            ListItem selectedListItem = layouts.Items.FindByValue(clientarray);
                            if (selectedListItem == null)
                            {
                                error.Visible = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                selectedListItem.Selected = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and In the aspx file I have

```
 <form runat="server" name="aspnetform" method="post" action="UploadExpressAccess.aspx">
        <div style="margin: 25px auto; width: 500px; height: 845px;">
            <label>Select User</label>
                <br />
               <asp:ListBox ID = "users"  runat="server" Placeholder="Select User" CssClass="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-size="20"></asp:ListBox>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SearchButton" Text="Search"  CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" OnClick="SearchButton_Click"/>
```

Comment: Please provide some logic so we can attempt to reproduce your error.

Comment: You should post some code.   Can you show the controller?

Comment: @Neil This is webforms inside of MVC, What would be in the controller? Am I missing something?

Comment: `OnClick` references `SearchButton_Click`, but that function doesn't exist in the code you have shown

Comment: @Neil My apologies I fixed the post

Comment: @Neil I put a breakpoint in right at the first line of the the `SearchButton_Click` function but it never hits it, just returns 404

Comment: Inspect this using chrome developer tools, specifically the Network tab. This should tell you what is happening. None of the code you posted should cause the behavior you described. Is there more code? Does `UploadExpressAccess.aspx` exist? That is your action, make sure it exists.

Comment: My guess at the moment is due to the form tag. Possibly the event click from the button is not being fired due to the action on the form tag.

Comment: @mxmissile Yes that aspx does exist. That is where the button and dropdown is located.

Comment: So we are talking about 2 different aspx pages?

Comment: Its interesting to me because all the views in the MVC application I have built so far has worked fine. I added some pre-existing webforms and get this error. But it was an exact copy / paste from its previous application and I of course had to add the SQL connections and some of the name spaces

Comment: @mxmissle 

No, this is all on within one single aspx.

Comment: Ahh, ok, try removing the action attribute, see if that changes behavior.

Comment: @huwparry22 I intially had the form tag left as just a basic <form runat=server>, I made an edit to what I posted as an attempt to see if I got anything else different out of it

Comment: @mxmissile Changed to just <form runat=server> which is what I had originally, No difference. Same error.

Comment: @mxmissile I added that attribute earlier, to see if it changed behavior. lol

Comment: Another guess is perhaps the routing of the MVC app needs updating to correctly route requests to *.aspx pages. Something I've found here might help...

http://www.codedigest.com/posts/3/adding-aspnet-webforms-into-aspnet-mvc-project-and-vice-versa

Comment: @huwparry22 I have looked over that article already. If the routing was incorrect would it even render the page in the first place? I am only getting error on postback

Comment: Does the URL change when posting? What does chrome tools tell you?

Comment: @mxmissle what specifically should I be looking at under networking?